# Problems In Merged CHM Help file

Tags: chm

I've succeeded to merge 2 chm files into one but

1. Application context sensitive help is not working now. Before, links were like "HELP/Outline1.htm". If I keep like that, it founds the subject in contents, locates it there but no help is displayed but page not found. Then, if I click on the subject, help text appears. If I change the link to HELP.chm::/HELP/Outline1.htm, help text appears but it cannot locate the subject on the left.

I wonder what is needed to open a help page in a merged help file and locate its subject in contents?

1. Is it possible to dive a chm file into two but context hierarchy should be same. What I mean is, I don't want to create another book. I need to open help context from another help file in a link

   - A 
     -- A.a 
     -- A.b
   - B

Currently I can only divide such a CHM into two but it becomes like below

- A 
  -- A.a
- B
- A.b

Is it possible to divide chm and keep the content list as same

Regards,
Burak

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really dove into merged chms yet, but I can share some urls from my notes. They are fairly common ones, so you might already have them. The second one is explicitely about context ids in merged help

http://www.helpware.net/htmlhelp/how_to_merge.htm

http://www.helpware.net/htmlhelp/how_to_merge_ctx2.htm